# Is there any added advantage on applying more ground stiching vias?

Tags: pcb-design

I am new to pcb design and i am hearing more about ground via stiching. My questain is there any extra benefit placing more stiching ground vias in PCB.

Comment: More than what? More than none, definite yes. More than one per square millimetre, definite no.

Comment: View every via as 1 nanoHenry and 1 milliohm resistance. Are more in parallel useful? Do you have high currents or high frequencies, or both?

Comment: I have both on my board!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have enough, there's no need for more.

If you're stitching for RF, there's no point in having them closer than lambda/20, and lambda/10 might well be enough.

If you're stitching them for thermal or electrical conductivity, then you need to do the conductivity sums properly. Solder filled vias will be more conductive than open vias.